# How to find from where file was downloaded?

Tags: php, asp.net, operating-system, windows-xp

1.is there any way by which we can know the file was downloaded from this specific website.?
2.i am using windows xp professional os.
3.And i found that in mac os it is possible with 'get info' command and it tells us the file was downloaded from this site and from this server.
4. is there any way in php by which we can know from which search engine our website was searched?

Answer (score 0):

1 - None that I'm aware of. I assume you mean files downloaded on local drive. If downloads are not passed through some additional step writing website info then there is no consistent info about file origin (you could parse browsers history, but it is unreliable and complicated)

4 - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` note: not working with google and https websites

Comment: but if we downloaded file a month ago and want to know from where it came and also deleted history then still can we know its origin place from where it downloaded?
and also $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] tells hostname or website name but it can not tell us from which search engine is website searched?

Comment: No, as I wrote it is unreliable method. You would have to force users to use the same browser, same settings (download directory), and not to clear download history. Even then it is no trivial task. Most reliable solution would be to create download manager plugin for browser, and force users to use this plugin. But it is a lot of work. Maybe you could write a little more details about this requirement?

Comment: my requirment is nothing but as i explained here that i downloaded one software from the website that i dont remember now.
so i just want to know if there is any way or any method to get that website name.
and i had deleted my browser history and also would like to tell that software was downloaded month or 2 month ago.
Thnx in advance